# Client side validation in openerp

Tags: python, python-2.7, openerp-7

I am still learning Openerp and please bear it if I asked something very simple.
My issue is that I need to get validate two fields which represent start_time and end_time.

both fields are in char

```
'start_time': fields.char('Start Time'),
'end_time': fields.char('End Time'),
```

What I need to do is , once the user input this start_time and end_time I need to check if that input is in 24hrs and in **hh:mm** pattern.

please be kind enough to  help me with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add an on_change function to your python code where you check if start_time and end_time is in the correct format. And in your xml you'll have to tell that the method should be called when the field changes.

**XML**

```
<field name="start_time" on_change="check_hour_format(start_time)"/>
<field name="end_time" on_change="check_hour_format(end_time)"/>
```

**Python**

*the result should be something like*

```
def check_hour_format(self,cr,uid,ids,time_field,context=None):
    if correct format  
       return {}
    else:
        warning = {'title'  : _("Warning for this value!"),
                   'message': _("Field not in correct format!"),
                  }
        return {'warning': warning}
```

*This code should work for this issue*

```
import time
    def check_hour_format(self,cr,uid,ids,time_field,context=None):
        try:
            time.strptime(char_input, "%H:%M")
            return {}
        except ValueError:
            warning = {'title'  : _("Warning for this value!"),
                       'message': _("Field not in correct format!"),
                      }
            return {'warning': warning}
```

*In on_change method, you can change field value*

```
def on_change(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    # do something
    return {'value': { 'field_name': newValue},
            'warning': {'title': _("Warning"),
                        'message': _("warning message")
                       }
           }
```