# Client side validation Openerp

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, openerp-7

This is with reference to my question regarding [Client side validation in openerp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36714045/client-side-validation-in-openerp)

I need to clarify it further more and please be kind enough to help me with that.

What I need to know is , even though I checked the value and get the error message once the result is false ; once the error message closed I still can save the wrongly typed value.

Please help me to avoid that until you entered the correct value you can not proceed with.

checking field will be,

```
'start_time': fields.char('Start Time'),
```

and the function will be,

```
def check_start_time(self,cr,uid,ids,start_time_check,context=None):
    starting_time=start_time_check
    try:
        time.strptime(starting_time, "%H:%M")
        return True
    except ValueError:
        raise osv.except_osv(('Error'), ('Start time not in hh:mm format (Eg: 08:30)'))
```

Comment: You can call the `check_start_time` function one more time in the `write` or `create` method then it can't be saved until the correct value is entered.

Comment: There is one create method already in the class, can I call another create method for the same class again ?? Thank you so much for the quick support btw...

Comment: Can't you just edit the existing `create` method?

Comment: current create method is using for concat **start_time** and **end_time**.

Comment: all you need to do is add a call to `check_start_time` within the `create` method. if that's not doable, you can use constraint like @Dome suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the default methods in the model. You don't need a new create method, if you have one. Just insert your field condition.
(In your case you have to override both of create and write, because create run when user want to create a new record and write run when user want to update a record.)

Another solving, when you use constraints.

**Python**

```
def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
    try:
        time.strptime(starting_time, "%H:%M")
     except ValueError:
         raise osv.except_osv(('Error'), ('Start time not in hh:mm format (Eg: 08:30)'))
    # do something
    return super(ModelName, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context)

def write(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
    try:
        time.strptime(starting_time, "%H:%M")
     except ValueError:
         raise osv.except_osv(('Error'), ('Start time not in hh:mm format (Eg: 08:30)'))
    # do something
    return super(ModelName, self).write(cr, uid, vals, context)



def _check_startTime(cr, uid, ids):
    try:
        time.strptime(starting_time, "%H:%M")
        return True
     except ValueError:
        return False

_constraints = [(_check_startTime, 'Invalid format!', ['start_time'])]
```

[Here is a very useful cheat sheet.](https://www.odoo.com/files/memento/OpenERP_Technical_Memento_latest.pdf)